Using complex objects as dictionary keys in Python
So I'm working XML files and am not quite sure if what I'm doing is 'Pythonic' enough.
The XML file has tagged text and I want to get all paragraphs that contain countries and rivers. So each paragraph must at least mention a country name and river name. My approach is to first make a paragraph to river and paragraph to country mapping, by simply using lxml.etree.Element as a key. Then I just turn both set of keys into sets and take the intersection, giving me paragraphs that should contain both countries and rivers.
My question: Is this slow in Python? Because I'm more familiar with Go and C and I do remember that in Go, you usually explicitly tell it when it should use a pointer to the object rather than the object itself, since for this operation, I technically speaking only need a reference to the object and not the object itself.
So I'm unsure if Python automatically uses pointers or if just hashes the object to some unique value to make it work. Both dictionaries and sets are using hash function in the backgrond, at least when I worked in C, I had to implement them myself and they are very similar in that aspect. So I assume Python will be using hashes under the hood but I'm wondering if I should do explicit references as well or if my approach will work good enough as it is?
I tried for example using id() on the xml.etree.Element objects and made two more dictionaries mapping these ids to the paragraphs, then performed the intersection on the ids instead. I ran the function 100 times and then computed the average time and there were no significant differences...

A key of dict in python should be either an unchangable object (like int, str, tuple) or an hashable object (it must implement the __hash__ method).  I don't know what do you mean by slow or slower than what.

Slow as in, is my approach the natural approach or is it more pythonic to do something else? Because my approach is what I did in Go but there I used pointers, whereas in Python, it seems like I'm passing in the whole object, which is hashable. I'm not sure if Python does the same as I would have to do manually automatically.

Usually we use reference instead of pointers in Python. When you run a=1, a memory block stored the value 1 is created and a name a points to a reference to that. When you run b=a, it is actually a reference to the memory block of the value 1 passed from a to b, a and b are now pointing at the same memory space but both doesn't own the memory space.  If you feel your work slow and want to reduce the cost of time, I think you should provide your specific code.
